# Symfony SerializerInterface deserialize json to class not working

Tags: json, symfony, serialization, symfony5

Here is my controller code for receiving POST request with JSON body which then I would like to deserialize into my dto. Sounds easy but for some reason does not work as expected. One of the properties is array of objects and when deserialized it is being deseriliazed into array of arrays

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use App\Dto\CreateDto;

class EntryController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("", methods={"POST"})
     *
     */
    public function createEntry(Request $request)
    {
        $content = $request->getContent();

        $entry = $this->serializer->deserialize($content, CreateDto::class, 'json');

        ...
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
<?php

namespace App\Dto;


class CreateDto
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $items; // this is CreateDto[]
}
```

I make a request using postman POST request with body content type json

> ```
>  {
>         "name": "Example",
>         "email": "example@example",
>         "items": [
>                {
>                   "name": "sub",
>                   "email": "somethig@example.com"
>                }
>          ]
>     }
> ```

Symfony version 5.0.8

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare which fields are seriliaze or deseriliaze.

```
<?php

namespace App\Dto;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;


class CreateDto
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"api""})
     */
    public $name;
    /**
     * @Groups({"api""})
     */
    public $email;
    /**
     * @Groups({"api""})
     */
    public $items; // this is CreateDto[]
}
```

After that

```
 $entry = $this->serializer->deserialize($content, CreateDto::class, 'json', ["groups" => "api"]);
```

Give serializer to which groups to serialize or deserialize. Like that.

Comment: Hi, the properties are deserialized  in my case but the property "items" in the deserialized object is not array of objects as I would expect it to be but the array of arrays in which each "item" object is array

Comment: @StackNet then you need to give type $items. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-serialization-depth look at that.

Comment: Do you mean adding   /**
     * @var self[]
     */
on property $items? because I tryied that but same problem. Still deserializing into array of arrays

Comment: I am not entirely sure but adding "@var self[]" or  maybe "@var CreateDto[]" must solve your problem. But problem is $items type. You need to tell serializer to $items property is  "CreateDto" type then serializer will deserialize this to CreateDto object instead of array.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. still debugger says its array